# Linear Complexity in my program?

Tags: c, arrays, time-complexity, linear-programming

Some time ago I ask in codereview.stackexchange a review for one of my problems. I din't get a sufficient answer and many people told me to post a question here just to get more answers and solutions. My problem is the follwoing.

> Giving a dynamic array, we want to pass the array elements from a
>   file. The first number in the file N gives us the array length. They
>   follow N numbers, the actual elements of the array.
>
> Three brothers are going to work in the shop of their father for a time. The >shop is doing well and every day generates profit which the
>   three brothers may provide. The brothers agreed that they would divide
>   the total time in three successive parts, not necessarily equal
>   duration, and that each one will be working in the shop during one of
>   these parts and collects the corresponding profit on his behalf. But
>   they want to make a deal fairly, so that one received from three more
>   profit someone else. Specifically, they want to minimize the profit
>   the most favored of the three will receive.

Now I created a solution with O(n^2) complexity but I want to know if someone has any other idea to solve the problem with linear complexity.

Lets assume we have the follwoing input :

`1 1 8 1 1 3 4 9 5 2`

The output is `15`.

`A=1+1+8+1+1+3` , `B=4+9=13` , `C=5+2=7`

Remenber I want linear complexity. If someone believe it's  just a homework to be done and I boring then he has no place here. I just want to know if someone has any idea how to solve the problem in **C**.

My try was the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define max(A,B,C) A > (B > C ? B : C) ? A : (B > C ? B : C)
#define N 10

int main()
{
    int e[N] = {1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 3, 4, 9, 5, 2 };
    int i=0;
    int j = N-1;
    int A = e[i];
    int C = e[j];
    int B = 0;
    int x, AL, CR, BL, BR, m, mp = INT_MAX, L, R;
    for(x = i+1 ; x < j; x++) B+=e[x];
    m = max(A,B,C);
    printf("A=%d B=%d C=%d\n", A, B, C);
    while(m < mp)
    {
        AL = A+e[i+1];
        CR = C+e[j-1];
        BL = B-e[i+1];
        BR = B-e[j-1];
        L = max(AL,BL,C);
        R = max(A,BR,CR);
        if(L<R)
        {
            A=AL;
            B=BL;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            C=CR;
            B=BR;
            j--;
        }
        mp = m;
        m = max(A,B,C);
        printf("A=%d B=%d C=%d MAX=%d\n", A, B, C, m);
    }
    printf("%d", mp);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't want someone to base in the above code cause it gives wrong outputs in 90% of the most inputs.

Comment: Clarify this: "But they want to make a deal fairly, so that one received from three more profit someone else"

Comment: @asimes see the input example. We want to minimize the profit who recieve the brother-with-most-profit.  As you see in the example the days isn't suffled.

Comment: I asked for clarification because the sentence is grammatically incorrect and I can't guess the meaning. Also, why is A given so many `1` in your example? A has the maximum profit, if that is to be minimized then giving two of the `1` to C would bring A down to B

Comment: @asimes we can't shuffle  the days. The Brothers work in continue time. and all brothers work at least one day